# Laravel Token For Password Reminder Always Mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, token, remember-me

Hi there i have some strange problem for password reminder system. The return for this function is always password token mismatch.

here is the **remember controller**

```
  <?php

 class RemindersController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display the password reminder view.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getRemind()
{
    return View::make('resetacc');
}

/**
 * Handle a POST request to remind a user of their password.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postRemind()
{
    switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
    {
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', Lang::get($response));
    }
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return Response
 */
public function getReset($token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

    return View::make('resetpass')->with('token', $token);
}

/**
 * Handle a POST request to reset a user's password.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postReset()
{
    $credentials = Input::only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();
    });

    switch ($response)
    {
        case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
        case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
            return Redirect::to('/reset')->with('message', Lang::get($response));
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', Lang::get($response));
        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return Redirect::to('/auth')->with('message', 'Password Reset anda berhasil, silahkan login.');
    }
}

}
```

and the **Routes.php**

```
Route::get('reset', function() {
    return View::make('resetacc');
});

Route::get('password/reset/{token}', array(
    'uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset',
    'as' => 'resetpass'
));
```

the token stored in database is equally the same with the one given to user.

i have the laravel version 4.1 then updated to 4.2.5

is it because of the update process?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add something like `{{ Form::hidden('token', $token) }}` into your reset form.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness: This error could also mean that the token is simply expired.

You can set `reminder.expire` in `config/auth.php`.

Default is 60 minutes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#after-resetting-passwords

Comment: This was my case... Sad that the error is not explicit. Must say "Token expired" or something similar...

Answer (score 2):

If you have **subdomain** routing in your application, you will have to modify your getReset method to include the subdomain parameter in the function's parameter list.

```
    public function getReset($club="",$token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        return view('auth.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }
```